# Xcode 11 : Build failed for swift framework with aggregate

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, swift-framework

Same framework was building fine on Xcode 10.x version. On upgrading to Xcode 11, I can now see the following errors :

[image]
[image]

**Note : Already tried locking and unlocking Keychain access -> Login. Didn't work.**

Comment: Did you try deleting your derived data?

Comment: @SivajeeBattina : I did.